# How to use a git sub repository pushing to a private remote but pulling also from its original origin

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote, git-subtree

I need to setup a repository like this:

- *rep* (pull & push from/to *private remote*)

  - normal stuff
  - *sub-rep* (pull from *private remote* & *public remote* and push to *private remote*)

    - stuff in *sub-rep*
    - *sub-module* (pull from *private remote* & *public remote* and push to *private remote*)

      - stuff in *sub-module*

*rep* is the repository I'd like to set up

*private remote* is my own remote repository.

*sub-rep* is the inclusion (`submodule` or `subtree`) of another repository fetched from *public remote* as a sub folder in *rep*. As I read that there are two ways of including another repository I simply write ''sub repository'' instead of `submodule` or `subtree`.

*sub-module* is a `submodule` inside *sub-rep*

The requirement is that all commits I make in *rep*, *sub-rep* and *sub-module* can be pushed to my *private remote*, so that I can continue my work from somewhere else. But I still want to be able to receive updates from the *public remote*. And at this point, no commit I make should be pushed to the *public remote*.

The key should be to use multiple remotes, but I'm not sure how to handle the repository inside repository (inside repository...) thing right. As the setup will be relatively complex (I think) an additional workflow example would be very helpful.

Comment: Thats confusing. Is root/sub a submodule? What is "an official platform"? Do you have commit access to "an official platform"? It sounds vaguely like you are describing maintaining a fork of a public project.

Comment: I changed "official platform" to "public platform". It is just a public repository I don't have commit accesss to. root/sub is meant to be the folder the sub repository is in.

Comment: What exactly is a "sub repository"? If you dont have commit access to the public platform there doesn't seem to be any complexity since it's not possible for you to push to the public repo. It'd be easier to understand if you used real (or aliased) repositories, folder names and git-config instead of abstract terms which are ambiguous.

Comment: I restructured my question and I have to correct myself: I am not sure whether I have commit access or not. It is quite possible that I have.

Comment: It's not really any clearer - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using your nomenclature, think of your private remotes as the origins and the public remotes as the upstream repositories.

1. First, define the submodule hierarchy:

   - Add *sub-module* as a git submodule to *sub-rep*.  You can do this by adding a .gitmodules file into *sub-rep* with contents similar to this:

     `[submodule "sub-rep/sub-module"]
       path = sub-rep/sub-module
       url = https://github.com/privateremote/sub-module.git`
   - Add *sub-rep* as a git submodule to *rep*

   To let git update your whole tree recursively, you can use the following command:
    `git submodule update --init --recursive`
2. Now you can define aliases to the remote URLs of the public repositories:

   - Go to the root of the local sub-module repository, then:
     `git remote add upstream https://github.com/somepublicremote/sub-module.git`
   - Do the corresponding thing for *sub-rep*:
     `git remote add upstream https://github.com/someotherpublicremote/sub-rep.git`

     *You can use some other alias name if you prefer, such as 'myupstream'*
   - Use this command to verify your setup:
     `git remote -v`
3. Using the above setup:

   - Update your origin from upstream:
     `>git checkout master`
     Make sure you are on the desired branch. 'master' is just an example
     `>git fetch upstream`
     Fetch all branches from 'upstream' .

     Now you can either merge some upstream branch into your local copy above your local changes:
     `>git merge upstream/master`

     ..or you might want to rebase so that your local changes will be removed and reapplied on top of the updated local repo:
     `>git rebase upstream/master`

     After resolving all conflicts, you can push the result to the origin:
     `>git push -f origin master`

I use a similar setup to push to my origin and to update my origin from the upstream.